# ffmpeg scale/forcing fixed video resolution issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I try to be sure that the `video comes out` with a `resolution` of `1920 x1080`,
If not the encoding `must force this resolution`.
I need this to create fine adaption set from a video input with standard resolution (HD).

> Im unable to get always this resolution, for example with a movie of
>   1920 x 1040 i get 1993 x 1080

, below my ffmpeg command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo1080.png -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=1920:1080" format1080.mp4
```

I tried every possibility that the ffmpeg scale page tells, without understand how to fix it. 
I think i need some help, 
Thanks, 
Massimo

Comment: did you try it with `-s 1920x1080` and remove scaling ? (if you don't know where to put the parameter, put it before `-r $FPSC`)

Comment: Hi Kamilz is the whole afternoon that i try both methods,1920x1072 is the input file, with -s i got 1932 x 1080 with scale "scale=-1920:-1080" i got 1920 x 1072, no way to get fixed resolution. below my last try: 

ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo1080.png -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -s 1920x1080 -r $FPSC -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" format-1080.mp4

Comment: the problems seems to arise only when the process have to add more area

Comment: i also try -s hd1080

Comment: Share the full log of your command.

Comment: @Mulvya i did !

Comment: Don't see it in your answer. Anyway, I think I know what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry, do you need more info? what you mean for full log? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP4box appears to consider the SAR-corrected dimensions i.e. it considers the frame dimensions to be `iw*sar x ih`. ffmpeg's scale filter adjusts the output's SAR so as to preserve the input's DAR. In this case, `1920/1040` = `1920 x newSAR/1080`, so `1920 x new SAR == 1993`.

You can sidestep this problem by setting SAR to `1` after the scale.

```
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1"
```

Comment: i read about dar and sar but i lost my self between -s -vf and -filter_complex, To be sure i immediately start to encode with your correction on the same video (total recall on 13inch 2014 mac..) in 3 hours i can give you my feedback, I am optimistic, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for disponibility, i think there will be a little mistake but i can't understand where, i try to bring all steps!

Below the bash i writing also with the help of stackoverflow users:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ENCODING FOR MPEG DASH

echo "ENCODE DASH-READY PROCESS"

echo -n "Insert input file name (es: input.mp4) and press [ENTER]: "
read name

DUR="$(ffmpeg -i $name 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | sed 's@\..*@@g' | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }')"

FPS="$(ffmpeg -i $name 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p")"
FPSC=$( echo "($FPS+0.5)/1" | bc )

eval $(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width $name)
size=${streams_stream_0_height}

GOP="$((FPSC*2))"
DURM="$((DUR%2))"
FDUR="$(($DUR-$DURM))"
# :no-open-gop=1:crf=16
# -c:a copy 
# -vf "scale=-1:1080”


ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo.png -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -s hd1080 -r $FPSC -b:v 4800k -maxrate 4800k -bufsize 3000k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" format-1080.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i format-1080.mp4 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -s 640x360 -r $FPSC -b:v 800k -maxrate 800k -bufsize 500k -profile:v main -t $FDUR format-360.mp4


#clear
echo duration in seconds $FDUR 
echo fps $FPSC 
echo height resolution $size 
echo I-frames GOP $GOP
#MP4Box -info TRACK_ID format.mp4 2>&1 | grep GOP
echo "format-1080.mp4 ready"
echo "format-360.mp4 ready"
echo "ENCODE COMPLETED"
```

It prepare two representation, the second one is created from the first.
As i said i wish that this script become able to process more kind of video possible: if the input videos have not the spec required (ex: gop, Resolution HD 1920 x 1080), the encoding must force them to generate another adaption set from the HD one, this to avoid non conventional resolution, like cinema scope or everything is not 1920 x 1080 to generate fine small version of the HD one.

now the facts become unclear:
if i use `ffmpeg -i format-1080.mp4`
i got that the resolution is 1920 x 1080
but if i check the fileinfo (note that i try on osx in this moment) it say 1993 x 1080, and is the same that say MP4Box when i try to dashify:

```
[DASH] Files have non-proportional track layouts (1993x1080 vs 664x360) but sample size and aspect ratio match, assuming precision issue
```

I know that it work fine if the first video input is 1920 x 1080, the second is 640 x 360 all works.

My ffmpeg version is 3.4.1
The original video for the experiment is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'total.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-08-10T11:02:57.000000Z
  Duration: 01:53:31.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2211 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1040 [SAR 1:1 DAR 24:13], 2111 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 96 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-08-10T11:02:58.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-08-10T11:13:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
```

And above you can cleary see that original resolution is 1920 x 1040.
Seems to be issues when i try to add more area without proportions from the original resolution, seems that the scale correction work fine only if the video have to become more small then the original.
Some ideas?
Thansk!
Massimo